# Error expected identifier or '(' int &arrayreturn[I] = {I}

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

```
#include "stdio.h"

int printsomething(int *array, int arrayreturn[5]) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
       int &arrayreturn[i] = {i};
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int array[10] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    // int *arraypointer = &array;
    int arrayp[5];
    int i;
    printsomething(array, arrayp);
    for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        printf("%d\n", arrayp[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am learning C and right now just playing with arrays and pointers trying to get comfortable. This bit of code has the goal of passing an array to a function, which was successful before I added the second part. That second part being assigning values in the called function to an already initialized array. Since we can't directly return an array I understood this was the way to do it. What exactly do you all think is going wrong here? And I just completely off the target?

Comment: First of all, C and C++ are two *very* different languages. Please don't try to mix them. Secondly, `int &arrayreturn[i] = {i};` just doesn't make any sense in C, but I'm ***guessing*** what you really want is just plain `arrayreturn[i] = i;`

Comment: About "That second part being assigning values in the called function to an already initialized array." The array `int arrayp[5];` has *not* already been initialized.

Comment: Aside: you would usually `#include <stdio.h>` unless you have supplied a local replacement for the library.

Comment: @WeatherVane sorry removed the wrong tag. OP says it is C thats why it is C

Comment: @weathervane didn't I include studio.h? I just used "" rather than <>. Also I remove the '&' from 'int &arrayreturn[i] = {i};' and now I get "variable sized object may not be initialized"

Comment: @JoshZ if you want to use the standard header it's `#include <stdio.h>`. If you want to use a local library it's `#include "stdio.h"`. In this case the compiler first looks in the local folder, and then in the library folder.

Comment: Also please read the [first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75233148/error-expected-identifier-or-int-arrayreturni-i#comment132757361_75233148) again more carefully, and the answer now posted.

Comment: I figured it out! I removed the & as @Someprogrammerdude said, and I removed the 'int' and '&' from arrayreturn[I] = i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to assign values to the array elements you need to use `[]` to access the elements and `=` to assign them. I cannot really explain your code because it is unclear how you came to the conclusion that you need to write `int &arrayreturn[i] = {i};`. Your loop can be this:

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
   arrayreturn[i] = i;
}
```

Comment: I'm honestly not sure how I got there either, but thank you for the help it worked!! Starting to make a lot more sense now

Answer (score 0):

the first problem is that when you have a parameter of the form `int arrayreturn[5]` you actually just pass an int pointer not an entire array of 5 elements. `int arrayreturn[5]`  and `int *arrayreturn` compile to exactly the same cpu instructions. I never use the `int arrayreturn[5]` syntax because i think it is confusing so i rather just pass a pointer and this is common practice as far as i know.

secondly in the second part of your code you try to declare a new array of size i by calling `int &arrayreturn[i] = {i}` this is not possible because of multiple reasons mostly because you cant dynamically allocate arrays on the stack. it should be `arrayreturn[i] = i`